# convert ppm image to black and white c++

Tags: c++

First, I'm new on the site.
I have a question, I need to write a program to convert a image.ppm to a black and white image. I need to use the RGB values.
I have the image so, that I can open it in a text file. I need to change the values in the text file, so that the image turns into black and white, but I don't know how. 
I hope somebody can help me with this.

Comment: There are existing image manipulation programs that you could use to do the job or at least get an idea what the outcome is supposed to look like. The point is that without having a goal, you couldn't even distinguish a correct from a flawed solution, which makes your whole question pointless.

Comment: [Parsing](https://github.com/marcodiiga/gp2univpm/tree/master/code/common) a normal P6 ppm is a straightforward task. And so is assigning a BW value to each RGB triplet (there are more than one solution available). Your question sounds a bit broad to me, try narrowing it down to your specific issue.